# Multi-key hotkey combinations don't work on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys, gnome-shell

On Ubuntu 18.04, hotkeys that have more than 2 keys aren't working for me.

For example in PHPStorm there are combinations like <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> AND <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>. Of these, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> works correctly, but <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> doesn't work - instead of the action it should trigger, it triggers the same action as <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>, as if <kbd>shift</kbd> hadn't been pressed at all.

All the keys are working; it's not a keyboard problem.

Other 3-key shortcuts behave in the same way, as if two of the keys had been pressed.

What could be the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: Did you try in Settings -> Keyboard (Keyboard Shortcuts) click "Reset All..."? Is **GNOME Tweak Tool** is installed? GNOME Tweak Tool have own shortcuts settings.

Comment: Yeap. I was trying. actually there were only default settings.
GNOME Tweak Tool not installed